# $ is not a valid function in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

So I'm going to publish my Tampermonkey userscript (It's a button to get you to a random link in the list) to the Chrome Web Store, I have been testing it today and I got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at Chain Finder.user.js:258
    at Chain Finder.user.js:261
```

If you want to take a look at my script:

```
(function() {
    const $ = window.$;

    var randomLink = function () {
        // Beggining of target list
        var links = [
            "torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2410074",
            "torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2393322",
            "torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2049797",
            "torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2268673",
            "torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2059647"
            // More links.... but I cut them so it's easier to understand.
        ];

        // End of target list
        // by counting the number of links in the array
        var max = (links.length)

        // now generate a random number
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);

        // use that random number to retrieve a link from the array
        var link = links[randomNumber];

        // change the location of the window object
        return "https://" + link;
    }

    // Opens a new tab.
    function openInNewTab(url) {
        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    }

    function main() {
        $('.buttons-list').append(`<a id="mc-btn" href="#" class="profile-button" style="width:99px;text-align:center">
                  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/TQdk3Pp.png'>
                                  </a>`);
        $('#mc-btn').on('click', () => openInNewTab(randomLink()));
    }

    //Here's the error:

    $(document).ready(() => {
        main();
    });
})();
```

If you could tell me what's wrong in there, I will be very grateful.

**Edit: I've learned JavaScript. It all seems so easy now! Thank you for the help either way.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that somewhere in your script that you include these two lines of code, put var $ = window.jQuery; above where you code starts, and put // @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js somewhere up top with the rest of the // lines.

Example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Example
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description
// @author       Username
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
// @grant GM_addStyle
// @grant GM.listValues
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_getValue
// @match *
// @match https://*/*
// @match http://*/*
// @match *://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
})();
var $ = window.jQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually displayed if Jquery is not included in the script.

Comment: Try including a jQuery <script> on top of the Tampermonkey script and run it again.